# PHPMailer: Can't send email to any kind of domain

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new to PHPMailer. I am able to send emails to email addresses like abc@gmail.com. But I can't send any email to email addresses like myemail@office.com or myemail@officename.net. PHPMailer does not show any kind of error but it is not sending my email.Here is my phpMailer setup:

```
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');                   
$email = new PHPMailer(); 
$email->From = "info@mydomain.com"; 
$email->FromName = "Any Name"; 
$email->AddAddress("enam@domain.com");
$email->AddAddress("enam@domainn.net");
$email->isHTML(true); 
$email->Subject   = 'Order Confirmation';
$email->Body = "Hello. I am testing <b>PHP Mailer.</b>";                                
$email->Send();
```

Can anyone say how can i send email to email addresses of any kind of domain?

Comment: did you try smtp send mail?

Comment: No, I did not. How can i use smtp to send email? It will be helpful if you please elaborate the steps @AnishChandran

Comment: Use `try..catch()..`.. it will expose run time errors..

Comment: $email->isSmtp(); call added in your script and set smtp username and password

Comment: Refer https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582147-How-to-Send-with-PHPMailer

Comment: Please don't link to non-PHPMailer examples - they are not maintained and get out of sync. That mandrill one will not work with the current PHPMailer release. Always [go straight to the source](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples).